# Excel - Text to Rows & Columns?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a ugly export string coming from another script and I'm wondering if this is possible: E.g. if you have string:

```
row1_c1,row2_c1,row3_c1|row1_c2,row_2_c2,row3_c3
```

whats the easiest way to convert to:

```
row1_c1    row1_c2 
row2_c1    row2_c2
row3_c1    row3_c2
```

If I copy-paste the string into Excel, the text-to-column conversion happens automatically. But how do I deal with the text-to-rows? Is this possible via UDF?
I tried:

```
Public Function SplitEnumbersDown(in_ As String)
  Dim Enumbers() As String
  Enumbers = Split(in_, ";")
  Selection(1).Resize(UBound(Enumbers) + 1) = Application.Transpose(Enumbers)
End Function
```

But if I Change the export string to
 `=SplitEnumbersDown("row1_c1,row2_c1,row3_c1")|=SplitEnumbersDown("row1_c2,row_2_c2,row3_c3")`
 - this has a circular reference... Do I have a error somewhere?

I am aware of the text-to-column, and then paste Special with transpose, but I would like to have it done automatically.

So the end Goal is to copy paste the export string into Excel and automatically convert it.

Comment: Use a sub rather than UDF

Comment: You can use the Split Function or Regex or Text-to-column. And use the created Function on a Sub looping from the desired row to the lastRow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SplitString()
    Dim inputRange As Range, outputRange As Range
    Dim s() As String
    Dim al As Object
    Dim i As Long

    Set inputRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Set outputRange = inputRange.Offset(1, 0) 'output to cell(s) below
    Set al = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    s = Split(inputRange.Value, "|")
    For i = LBound(s) To UBound(s)
        al.Add Split(s(i), ",")
    Next i

    outputRange.Resize(UBound(v(0)), UBound(v)).Value = Application.Transpose(al.ToArray)  
End Sub
```

---

[image]

Comment: Is this possible via UDF? with a sub a user would have to 1. copy-paste the export, 2. start the sub.... 1 step would be nicer

Comment: A UDF can't access the worksheet. It can only return a single value to the cell it is contained in. It's the same as a normal formula in that sense. You could have the function return an array and create an array formula on the worksheet. But if you have more rows than the array formula spans your user would have to extend the array formula -- meaning they have more than one step. Is there always going to be the same number of rows (3) ?

Comment: Thanks - I just noticed that it won't work if I have an empty column... e.g. "row1_c1||row1_c3" .... it'll throw a type mismatch in the very last step.... ideas? or a new stack question?

Comment: Hmmm so it'll work if the columns are all of the same size... I can adjust to that... But a more flexible solution would of course be sexy ;)

Comment: I’d ask a new question if you want some extra functionality (but also try to use this answer/other resources to build in the functionality yourself before you ask!)